# What possible issues with running a fan inside a freezer?

Tags: fan, component-selection, cooling

I need to turn on a fan inside an ice cream display cabinet when the lid is closed, and turn the fan off as soon as the lid is opened.

I'm looking for a way to have as little temperature derivation as possible throughout the whole display cabinet. 
The ice cream pans (actually it's gelato) sit at the very top of the inside of the display cabinet and it is opened and closed frequently during operation, which causes a certain amount of ambient temperature air inside everytime it is opened.

I figured by positioning an appropriately sized fan at the bottom of the freezer that turns on when the lid is closed, that will move the colder air up and even out the temperature difference as much as possible.

I'm wondering if there are any issues with running a fan inside a freezer at -12 degrees celsius, or what type of fan would be more appropriate for this task.

Will the fan freeze? Maybe this is crazy..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would not be any problem unless your freezer produces "ice". Moreover electric motors can run more efficiently under the condition of low temperature.

But be careful. If ice which produced by your freezer freezes the motor shaft then it will act like as if it is almost a short circuit and draws dangerous amount of current. If this happens you can end up with a broken freezer.

Answer (score 3):

No the motor will not freeze. Dont believe the reduction in temperature will have any major impact on the motors performance curves either. However I don't know how effective the system will be in achieving your desired cooling response. Isn't the refrigeration unit's internal fans taking care of the uneven temperature?

If you would like some detailed reading here is a [link](http://www.pittman-motors.com/Portals/0/Resources/Temperature_Effects_On_DC_Motor_Performance.pdf). If you are worried about the performance it is best you refer to the motor's datasheet.

Comment: @tomnexus I have to reword that.